# UITextField resign first responder is not working in Containerview

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have container,in child class having some of the textfield after saved the  text field value,the child class textfield cannot resigned.i was resigned the textfield coding put inside the viewWillAppear method,textFieldShouldReturn and am trying to refresh the containerview by the following way,

```
 1.Begin Appearance Transition
 2.End Appearance Transition
```

but that is not resigned?please provide any solution fot that,much appreciated.

NOTE:textField delegate also set.

Answer (score 0):

Call this when you want all textfield resigns
`[self.container.view endEditing:YES]`

Comment: Hello DungProton,i was checked your code but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

Comment: Do the method textFieldShouldReturn has response?

Comment: i put this code inside the textfieldShouldReturn that delegate is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code to dismiss keyboard:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```